# Формула расчета вероятности подбора?

Tags: javascript, c++, математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить формулу расчета вероятности подбора промо-кода?
Есть несколько данных которые влияют на вероятность подбора

1. длина;
2. количество промо-кодов;
3. шаблон: только символы, только цифры, цифры + символы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просто случайного подбора, зная длину? посчитать общее количество возможных вариантов, поделить на него количество реальных кодов.

При длине N и наборе из K символов, которые могут повторяться - имеем K^N вариантов. Так что вероятность угадать равна количеству промокодов, деленному на количество используемых в промокодах символов в степени длины.

Так устроит?